# Formulating a particular constraint

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, numerical-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint-programming

I have a problem setting similar to bin packing but not exactly. I have to put the few boxes of certain dimensions in a square area besides each other. Like a grid. The boxes should be placed around defined point in the working area. So I tried my modeling something like this. This gives me the solution. But, there's a but....but I will come to that later soon.

**Pairwise distance between boxes**: Getting the minimum distance and later maximizing it to avoid overlapping of two boxes. This is as same as the p-dispersion problem.

\begin{align}
dist(b_{a} - b_{b}) >= minBoxBoxDistance
\end{align}

**Distance to the defined point**: For each box, calculate distance to this defined point and place the boxes to somewhere around this point.

\begin{align}
dist(b_k - centerPoint) >= minBoxPointDistance \\
distVar= dist(b_k - centerPoint)
\end{align}

My objective function is:

\begin{align}
minimize(distVar)
\end{align}

with this formulation I was able to get the results what I expect. **But**, only with the square boxes, i.e. equal length and width. When I try with rectangular boxes, some box overlap partially or sometimes fully.

**What I tried:**

1. So I tried to change this `minBoxBoxDistance` value, just by hit and try, but it is not yielding anything good.
2. Tried `Pairwise distance between boxes` constraint separately with `x-axis` and 'y-axis' but then I am only able to fit limited number of boxes, limited to 4 in some cases.

Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong?
Is there any similar standard optimization problem already?

PS: The pairwise distance between the boxes is **not given**. The number of boxes to fit is passed to the model and the center point is passed to the model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you computing the distance between two boxes?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Euclidean distance. Is it what you wanna know?

Comment: I can understand how you'd compute the Euclidean distance between two points. But a box is not a point, and this especially matters for rectangular boxes.

Comment: @MishaLavrov yeah I am interpreting them as points. You can also say them points

Comment: If boxes are points, then by enforcing a minimum box-box distance you are just treating the boxes as *circles* - not squares and certainly not rectangles.

Comment: yes! But the problem I want to solve is using variable box dimensions. Hence I am using one of the box dimension as  minimum box-box distance. So when I get my output in terms of set of points, I place box over them. With rectangular boxes they overlap

Answer (score 0):

If box dimensions are given $l,h$ & so are defined points $K$ then you'd need constraints like
$\sum_{i \in S_k} b_i+b_j \le 1$
where $S_k = \{(i,j) \in K:  d(i,j) \ge \Vert (l,h) \Vert_2 \}$